# How to access my organisation's GitHub repos with "AWS Connector for GitHub" in CodePipeline?

Tags: github, aws-codepipeline, aws-codestar

I'm trying to set up an AWS CodePipeline pipeline, which needs to access a GitHub repository owned by my organisation.  For the Source Action I have selected GitHub (version 2) as the provider.  When I try to create the connection, I am only able to select the AWS Connector for GitHub installation for my own account, and when I do this, the connection is created but I can only see my own personal GitHub repositories in the "Repository name" dropdown.

Alternatively, if I click "Install a new app" rather than selecting the installation associated with my own GitHub account, I am shown two installations with the option to "Configure" them - one for my account and one for my organisation.  Clicking "Configure" for my organisation, I can see that the connector is already configured to allow Repository access to the repo that I need.

So it seems to me that I either need to have permissions changed such that I can use my own connector to access my organisation's repos, or have permissions changed such that I am able to use my organisation's connector to create the connection for the pipeline.  Which is the recommended way of doing this and how are those permissions granted?

Comment: Were you able to overcome this? Did an org owner have to configure the _Applications_  permissions under _Settings/Integrations_ to allow you to use that connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can already see the connector, yes - you need your permissions updated. Assuming your organization is not using Federated Logins, your User Role or Group would need to be updated to give access.  I see you tagged with with CodeStar, so if its set up then your particular user account needs access to that Connection. This is assuming you have personal aws User accounts rather than Federated Logins through your orgs AD system. If you have a federated user access, then you should still reach out to your orgs iam permission gatekeepers, or if need be to AWS support.

Comment: " Federated Logins " - what is that ? Do the "Federated Logins" differ from IAM accounts ?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin Federated logins are part of AWS organizations, using often an external user system (like Microsoft AD) or in tandem with one to allow SSO through SAML connections with say, your work email.